# Remove spaces in one instance of variable?

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm having trouble figuring out how to remove spaces, quote marks and periods in the first instance of `$member['team_name']` (the one in the `rel` attribute) using `str_replace`.

```
foreach($members as $member) {
    echo '<div class="teamname" rel="' . $member['team_name'] . '">' . $member['team_name'] . '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_replace` should do it fine -

```
echo '<div class="teamname" rel="' . str_replace(' ', '', $member['team_name']) . '">' . $member['team_name'] . '</div>';
```

That will work for spaces, you could use `preg_replace` to remove a general whitespace pattern.

EDIT (having seen your edit!):

The `preg_replace` pattern you're probably after would be something like

```
echo '<div class="teamname" rel="' . preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '', $member['team_name']) . '">' . $member['team_name'] . '</div>';`
```

This will replace any non-alphanumeric character.  If you really only want spaces, quote marks and periods, you can go back to a `str_replace` with an array as the search argument - it will be faster.

```
str_replace(array(' ','"',"'",'.'), '', $member['team_name'])
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't realize that I could just add the preg_replace inline. I was trying to figure out how to create another string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_replace()` something like this:

```
preg_replace("/(?:\s|\t|\'|\.|\"')+/", "", $member['team_name'], -1)
```

That will remove all spaces, tabs, dots and either quote mark